# Какие ошибки алгоритма работы Android приложения?

Tags: android, алгоритм, архитектура

Уважаемые профессионалы! Учусь программировать, пробую сделать приложение, слайдер иллюстраций с озвучкой. Когда начал писать код, понял, что  тяжело держать в уме все взаимосвязи и логику программы. Воспользовался диаграммой ДРАКОН и составил алгоритм программы. Этот алгоритм представлен на рисунке ниже (кликабельно):
[image: Алгоритм программы - слайдера изображений]
Теперь собственно вопрос: подскажите пожалуйста опытным взглядом, какие ошибки в алгоритме с точки зрения разработки для Android?
Понимаю, что копаться в чужих схемах и диаграммах сложно. Но надеюсь на помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: Так архитектура или алгоритм работы?

Comment: Ну, во-первых по моему мнению это не архитектура. Это алгоритм работы приложения с разветвлениями.

Comment: Да, согласен, это просто алгоритм

Comment: В схеме очень много ошибок, начиная от типизации, связей, логики. Если рассматривать сам алгоритм, хотя по такой схеме это затруднительно, то ошибок не меньше. С меня вопрос к вам, какой ответ вы хотите увидеть, ведь вопрос не содержит конкретику и мб закрыт по этой причине, на него невозможно дать ответ, ибо придется всю схему за вас переделывать.

Comment: Был бы признателен на любой ответ по названным выше ошибкам. например, про типизацию. Что не так, где посмотреть примеры, как исправить

Answer (score 1):

1. Почему при отсутствии интернета завершение работы? Логично вывести предложение включить интернет и повторить действие после появления доступа
2. У вас на сервере медиафайлы mp3 и png, однако основной поток принудительно запускает `MediaPlayer` и "передает в него первый mp3". А что с PNG?
3. "Показана первая страница". Откуда!? У нас же предыдущим шагом `mp3` запустился?
4. "Показана первая страница". Дальше много вариантов, но они на 90% дублируют друг друга. Такой функционал надо объединять,а не разносить на отдельные блоки

Comment: 1. Если нет интернета, приложение завершается, потом пользователь на телефоне включает интернет и снова запускает приложение

Comment: 2. Запуск ViewPager сразу показывает вью с первой страницей из массива PNG. То есть нет необходимости расписывать работу ViewPager-а (это относится и к пункту 3)

Comment: 4. Да, теперь вижу смысл написать паблик метод для проверки состяния плеера и обращаться к нему, вместо отдельного кода в каждом случае